# Unrecognized image file format - UiBinder

Tags: java, gwt

I'm getting this error when I put

In my UiBinder file where the error is:

```
[DEBUG] [MyGWT] - Rebinding com.mycomp.mygwt.client.Resources
    [DEBUG] [MyGWT] - Invoking generator com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator
        [DEBUG] [MyGWT] - Preparing method logo
            [TRACE] [MyGWT] - Adding image 'com.mycomp.mygwt.client.Resources.logo'
                [ERROR] [MyGWT] - Unrecognized image file format
        [ERROR] [MyGWT] - Generator 'com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator' threw an exception while rebinding 'com.mycomp.mygwt.client.Resources'
```

The image file in the path is a PNG file which I use in my previous GWT application. I really don't know why GWT is throwing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be an issue with particular JDKs on some versions of Windows with some PNG files - try modifying the image slightly or using a different JDK to get around this issue.

More details and discussions on this problem:

- Reported on the GWT issue tracker http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5810
- Discussion on sencha.com including details on JVMs that seem to work http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?161485-GXT-on-build-server

Comment: I fixed it by following the solution from the GWT issue tracker which is to save the PNG image using GIMP

Answer (score 0):

Do you use cvs and chekced the image into this repository?

If yes you should check that the file type is set to binary for hte png suffix. Otherwise cvs assumes the file is a text file and potentially corrupts the file.

Comment: What do you mean? When I check the properties with Ubuntu, the type is 'image/png' and when I open it the image is ok

Comment: OK, if you can open the image and you see it, then this is not your problem.